# when it's running here : CFRelease(book); that EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_l386_GPFLT)

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

CFRelease(book); the variable of book is an object of ABAddressBookRef.
Why I got this crashed?
The entirely code below:

```
- (NSArray *)getAllContactsBeneathiOS9:(NSString *__autoreleasing *)err
{
    __block NSMutableArray *contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //1.Create Address Book instance.
    ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    //2.Request to access the Address Book
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(book, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if(granted){
            //Access Success
            NSArray * allPeople = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(book);

            for (int i = 0; i < allPeople.count; i++) {
                ABRecordRef alPeople = (__bridge ABRecordRef)(allPeople[i]);

                ZRContactItem *item = [[ZRContactItem alloc] init];

                NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(alPeople, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                NSString *middleName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(alPeople, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty);
                NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(alPeople, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

                ABMultiValueRef phone = ABRecordCopyValue(alPeople, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                CFArrayRef phoneArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phone);
                NSMutableArray *phoneList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                if (phoneArray) {
                    CFIndex phoneCount = CFArrayGetCount(phoneArray);
                    for (CFIndex j = 0 ; j < phoneCount; j++) {
                        CFStringRef mobile = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, j);
                        [phoneList addObject:(__bridge NSString *)mobile];
                        CFRelease(mobile);
                    }
                }
                if (phoneArray) CFRelease(phoneArray);
                if (phone) CFRelease(phone);

                ABMultiValueRef email = ABRecordCopyValue(alPeople, kABPersonEmailProperty);
                CFArrayRef emailArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(email);
                NSMutableArray *emailList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                if (emailArray) {
                    CFIndex emailCount = CFArrayGetCount(emailArray);
                    for (CFIndex j = 0 ; j < emailCount; j++) {
                        CFStringRef mail = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, j);
                        [emailList addObject:(__bridge NSString *)mail];
                        CFRelease(mail);
                    }
                }
                if (emailArray) CFRelease(emailArray);
                if (email) CFRelease(email);

                ABMultiValueRef address = ABRecordCopyValue(alPeople, kABPersonAddressProperty);
                CFArrayRef addrArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(address);
                NSMutableArray *addrList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                if (addrArray) { 
                    CFDictionaryRef dic = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(addrArray, 0);
                    NSString *city = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dic, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
                    NSString *CountryCode = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dic, kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey);
                    NSString *Country = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dic, kABPersonAddressCountryKey);
                    NSString *State = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dic, kABPersonAddressStateKey);
                    NSString *Street = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dic, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
                    NSString *ZIP = (__bridge NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dic, kABPersonAddressZIPKey);

                    NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    dic1[@"street"] = Street;
                    dic1[@"city"] = city;
                    dic1[@"state"] = State;
                    dic1[@"postalCode"] = ZIP;
                    dic1[@"country"] = Country;
                    dic1[@"countryCode"] = CountryCode;
                    [addrList addObject:dic1];

                    CFRelease(dic);
                }
                if (addrArray) CFRelease(addrArray);
                if (address) CFRelease(address);

                item.givenName = [self isnil:firstName];
                item.familyName = [self isnil:lastName];
                item.middleName = [self isnil:middleName];
                item.phoneNumbers = phoneList;
                item.email = emailList;
                item.address = addrList;
                [contactArray addObject:item];

                if (alPeople) CFRelease(alPeople);
            }
        }else{
            //Access denied.
            *err = @"Grant this application to access your Contacts, please! ";
            NSLog(@"%@", *err);
        }
        //Release book instance
        if (book) CFRelease(book);
    });
    return contactArray;
}
```

When it is running CFRelease(book); that is crashed. Why?
I have already determined the variable of book is not nil, so that it can release.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion is an asynchronous function. It returns immediately, and the block you pass to it is executed at some later point. The contact array you return will always be empty.

As for the crash, if you call CFRelease at all, it shouldn't be inside the block. You don't know what ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion does with the book reference after running the block!

Try doing a bridge transfer to an ARC managed property and just hold on to it while you work with the address book.

Comment: Can you give me the code? I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: After thoughtful consideration, I got an idea.
I copied book of the variable from stack area to heap area, the variable which is a heap variable, it crashed when I release a heap variable. Am I right?